# Mobile app as3 vs html5

Tags: android, iphone, html, actionscript-3, flash

I'm making an app for Iphone and android. And I'm wondering what the pros and cons are for flashcs6 (as3) and for html 5.

I'm into flash so I have no idea about the possibilities with html5, some guy pointed me on the fact that developing apps for andriod and iphone might be easier to do with hmtl5...

So I'm wondering what you guys think about this..

Greetings,
Merijn

Comment: I also heard html 5 is the way to go these days, don't know the pros or cons

Comment: Stack Overflow is more dedicated to concrete coding problems than this kind of high level conundrum. That being said, I would recommend developing native apps  for Android & iOS (java and objective c) if you try to deliver the best experience possible. html5 based solutions like phonegap will allow you to deliver an app for the 2 platforms but at the cost of quality (fluidity, respect of the platforms design guidelines). A mix of native and html5 makes sense in some cases (for exemple if you need to dramatically change a part of your app from the server side of things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is no "right" answer to this question, but an oppinion. HTML5 with JavaScript is looking promising in my oppinion. HTML5 is not yet "finished" but it is at least in parts implemented on newer mobile devices.

Check out [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com) for a demo of what you can do using HTML5 and JavaScript. Its a javascript game engine which shows that you can use this for IPhone and other smartphones. (As well as newer desctop browsers)

[Here](http://html5readiness.com/) you can find information about which browser how much of the html5 standard supports allready.

There are also other options depending on the type of app you want to create. For instance jQuery mobile can be used if its a "simple".

Comment: "iPhones does not support Flash" is not true anymore, check Adobe AIR.

Comment: Oh, thanks :) Did not know that. Anyway, I believe html5 will be the future. I just read version 2.7 of AIR does not support Linux anymore. So you'd again need to develop for two different platforms. Also you'd need a special plugin / software. HTML5 will work in different browsers without plugins.

Comment: @Zerd1984 Regarding AIR on linux... I think by looking at the market share and percent of users for linux you can understand why it is not supported any more. But regarding game development I will go for time/cost budget reasons for AIR solutions. Please check http://gaming.adobe.com   Also I consider HTML5 as the future but at this point it is too slow for the kind of the apps I am developing and Flex/Flash packaged AIR apps, which runs much faster even on ipad 1 and iphone 4.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu Point taken regarding AIR on Linux. What experiance did you make regarding performance compared to a nativ development using OGLES2? A bit off topic, but I'm curious.

Comment: Hi @Zerd1984. I think it is very difficult to achieve performance near the one offered by native app, but not impossible. Since stage 3d is available on most apple devices since AIR 3.1 (if I am not wrong) you could easily develop games using Starling (2d or isometric) or Away3D. I would say you should convince yourself on what is the best for you and not get someone advice and just do it. I can help you understand more what you can do with flash if needed. Here are some game samples, I suggest you install some of them and test them so you can compare better  http://gaming.adobe.com/showcase/

Answer (score 3):

I looked into using HTML5 for a mobile project a few months ago and found that it isn't yet as mature as AS3. It wasn't horrible - if I had decided to stick with it, I'm sure I could have made a great app. The problem was that there was no compelling reason to choose HTML5 over AS3, so I stuck with what gave me the easier development time. In a year or two from now, I imagine that HTML5 mobile dev will be a lot more mature and easier to work with though.

I can't speak feature to feature as I was just looking into making a game which just required being able to render to the screen and no device APIs (accelerometer, camera etc.). Performance-wise, AIR seemed to win out but not by a huge margin.

For now, it would come down to whether you want to pick up HTML5 (certainly a good skill to learn) or whether you want to just deploy as soon as possible in which case I would go with AS3 (more mature tools, libraries, etc.).